# importing php variables into stylesheet

Tags: php, css, import

I have a file – global.css.php – that contains php variables, for example:

```
$bglight = 'background-color: #ffe';
```

How can I use these same variables in other page-specific stylesheets on my site?

I've tried an @import of "global.css.php" on a page-specific stylesheet – page.css.php – but the variable doesn't carry over. And yes, both sheets have

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
```

on top.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use that variable from inside functions? Then you need to add global $bglight; in every such function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `@import` on the client you need to use `include` (php) on the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
@import of "global.css.php"
```

loads the CSS, not the PHP. If you want to use the PHP variables, you need to use PHP code - not CSS code - to achieve that:

```
<?php 

header("Content-type: text/css"); 
require(__DIR__ . '/global.css.php');
?>
```

You then have also the problem that you have the variables but also you merge the CSS with the include/require. So in the end you might want to create yourself one PHP file only containing the PHP variables with the CSS data in there which you then include/require in both of your CSS PHP files *global.css.php* and *page.css.php*.